# Call parent method in child class

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm learning the object model of Ruby. I've written this script:

```
#/usr/bin/ruby

module MyModule

  class MyBase
    def class_b_method
      puts "class_b_method called"
    end
  end

  class MyClass < MyBase
    attr_accessor :name

    class_b_method

    def set_name(name)
      @name = "My name is #{name}"
    end

    def display_name
      return @name
    end    
  end   
end

obj = MyModule::MyClass.new
obj.set_name "Martin"
puts obj.display_name
```

Running the code above I get this error:

```
module.rb:13: undefined local variable or method `class_b_method' for MyModule::MyClass:Class (NameError)
```

I'm trying to call the parent method within the class `MyClass`. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside class `MyClass`,self is `MyClass`.But you define `class_b_method` as an instance method inside class `MyBase`,i.e. method which can be called by the instances of the class `MyBase`,can't be invoked by the class itself. so `self.class_b_method` throws an legitimate error.To make your code workable write the method as below:

```
class MyBase
  def self.class_b_method
      puts "class_b_method called"
  end
end
```

Comment: If this answers your question, you should accept it so he gets more rep